# What is the probability that a couple has no common defective gene?

Tags: disease, genetics, reproduction

If a couple has no common defective gene, they can produce a big healthy population from just two people, right?

What is the probability that a human couple (especially of different races) has no common severly (minor defects like a gap in teeth that is a small health threat don't count) defective gene?

Present a calculation.

Comment: One's definition of "common" and "defective" are quite important for a question like this.  For example, different genes that affect different stages of a metabolic pathway might be considered "common". A sickle-cell hemoglobin gene might be considered severely defective if it produces sickle-cell anemia, but not defective if it lessens the severity of malaria infection.

Comment: Your starting assumption is wrong.  They can make a healthy first-generation population, but recessive defects can start pairing up in the second generation.

Comment: @Mark I did count all 4 variants of pairing. So your critique is wrong.

Comment: @porton I don't understand what you mean by "I did count all 4 variants of pairing." Could you clarify?

Comment: @Armand each parent has 2 genes, so there are 2x2=4 variants of pairing and I did take this into account.

Comment: @Armand You are wrong. Most of these 16 variants are the same because it is the same gene, no matter from which parent it is gotten if it is from the same "root ancestor".

Comment: @Armand I my opinion mutations are mostly irrelevant for the question because mutations are rare (compared to the size of the genome in genes). Why do you assume that I do not know that human genomes are almost identical? I do know this.

Comment: @Armand po;ymorphism increases the probability, so it does not make my lower bound of the probability computations wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If a couple has no common defective gene, they can produce a big healthy population from just two people, right?"

No. As described in the review "The genetic basis of disease" Essays Biochem. 2018 Dec 3; 62(5): 643–723. Published online 2018 Dec 3. doi: 10.1042/EBC20170053
"we now know that, on average, each individual has several hundred variants that are either known, or predicted, to be damaging to gene function, including roughly 85 variants that lead to truncated (incomplete) protein products."

Since a given 2nd generation offspring of a founding couple might have both their copies of a given gene be the exact same version from one grandparent, if that version is defective, both the offspring's copies will thus be defective. This is the consequence of inbreeding and is why for example conservation biologists try to preserve as many different individuals as possible as founders in a captive breeding program.

Answer (score -3):

[Genetically determined metabolic disorders are rare conditions that affect about one in 2000 newborn babies. These conditions can cause serious illness, and may cause death.](https://www.aboutkidshealth.ca/article?contentid=472&language=english)

[The size of human genome is 30000 genes.](https://www.genome.gov/human-genome-project/Completion-FAQ)

This means that the probability y of no common defects (due to no better data I could find, I calculate under the wrong assumption that all the fetuses in the study survive at least till birth) is calculated as 1-y = (1-p<sup>4</sup>)<sup>30000</sup> where p is the probability of a defect in a single gene, because there are 4 recombinations (I assume for simplicity the same probability for all genes and the same for men and women, I assume all people are from the same uniformly "intermixed" ethnos, and maximum one defect per gene).

Probability (under the same assumptions) of a baby to have a defect is 1/2000 = 1 - (1-p<sup>2</sup>)<sup>30000</sup>.

It remains to do math. Sage code:

```
var('p y')
p = find_root(1/2000==1-((1-p^2)**30000), 0, 1); p
find_root(1-y==(1-(p^4))**30000, 0, 1)
```

We have p = 0.00012911558610889591, y = 10<sup>-11</sup> that is almost impossible.

Comment: Calculations corrected.

Comment: Please present improved calculations

Comment: This is all arithmetic and no genetics. I don't think your question can be answered with arithmetic.

Comment: @CareyGregory what's wrong? It is a simple scientific model. That my model is far from perfect is mentioned by myself in my answer. **All** scientific calculations are arithmetic. So, again, what's wrong?

Comment: I simply don't think you can make the sweeping assumptions you're making and arrive at a reasonably accurate answer to your question. Genetics matters and it changes your assumptions, but you're not accounting for genetics. You're just doing math.

Comment: @CareyGregory the real probability seems to be above my result, because apparently errors concentrate in few big genes and thete are multiple ethnicities with different defects. So, I have likely found a lower estimation indeed.

Comment: @CareyGregory the real probability seems to be above my result, because apparently errors concentrate in few big genes and thete are multiple ethnicities with different defects. So, I have likely found a lower estimation indeed.

Comment: Also my calculations are enough exact to claim for sure that now there are many potential couples that could be sent to Mars and produce a population without big genetic defects.

Comment: @porton Genetically determined *metabolic* disorders are only a subset of all genetically determined disorders. Genes involved in metabolism are only a subset of all genes.  Your other assumptions are wrong as well. In particular, you are forgetting that 2nd generation and later offspring of a couple can inherit both copies of a given gene from one of the 2 founders, so each of the 2 founders must have no defective gene copies at all in order to prevent this. Thus, the answer to your first sentence question is "no".

Comment: @Armand on the second part of your response: I use 4th degree, so that's correct.